# using $_SESSION['fb_'.APP_ID.'_user_id']

Tags: php, session, app-id

I'm developing a fb application with php sdk 3.0 and I've noticed that Facebook starts a session that contain the app_ID like that: `$_SESSION['fb_'.APP_ID.'_user_id'];`
This session store the facebook uid of the connected user.
Is this a feature of PHP SDK or is not recommended to work with this session?

To explain: After login successfully to my fb app, I use this function to see the php sessions `print_r($SESSION);` and there is a session `$_SESSION['fb_173620963485_user_id'] = 123456;`WHERE 173620963485 is my appID and 123456 is my fb uid.

Is recommended to work with this session: `$_SESSION['fb_173620963485_user_id']` ?

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use this session for anything. Period.

Answer (score 1):

You should never need to touch the `$_SESSION['fb_..._user_id']` variable. Use the SDK like the documentation states and you will be much better off. If you want access to the user ID, just use:

```
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
```

Take the time and [read the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/), and that should help.